# In the word "plain", what is the metaphor underlying the sense "explicit, clear, evident"?

Tags: etymology, metaphors

[According to etymonline.com](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=plain), the word *plain* (as used in e.g. *explain* or *plain English*) first appeared in the sense of "flat, smooth, even". Later, the sense of "explicit, clear, evident" appeared.

I wonder,
**what is the metaphor involving flatness that points towards "explicit, clear, evident"?**

### Research

Other words that refer to "explicit, clear, evident" have underlying metaphors that are known from texts since ancient times:

- *lucid*: dark room (non-seeing) is lightened up by a candle (seeing).
- *clear*: the sky goes from cloudy (confusion) to clear.

Are there also old texts which use plain ("flat, smooth") as a metaphor for "explicit, clear, evident"? Where does this transferred sense come from?

Some guesses (without attested texts):

- A turbulent sea surface as opposed to a still and smooth one? A metaphor for the mind.
- A bumpy landscape as opposed to a flat surface? A metaphor for ease, uniformity, and simplicity of moving ahead.

Also, some possibly related words: *explicit* (unfold) and *unpack*.

Comment: The link (which you don't mention and I can't supply) between *plain* and *unadorned* seems apt.

Comment: @JimMack I appreciate the link. That hypothesis resonates with me. The unadorned is the _essence_ of something, the _core_. So when we "explain", we point out the essence without the embellishments that might otherwise appear.

Comment: If you look in the OED you'll find a lot of suggestive material with many different senses of the word in Middle English, but no definite statement to answer the question. The fact that all these senses (flat; unadorned; evident) seem to be 14th C or earlier, the comparative lack of texts from that era, and the lack of statements of authorial intent from that time ("I'm creating a metaphor *vs* I'm using an existing sense of the word") all mean a conclusive answer is unlikely to exist.

Comment: I'd label the broader use of *plain* as a direct extension of the word, over any metaphorical use.  After all, on day two of a company, "Quality Widgets" becomes a name with no implications of quality. Time can remove the imagery of a metaphor, if there was one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English word *plain* is borrowed from Latin, which had it from two Proto-Indo-European roots, [both with the shape *pelə-](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=pel%C9%99-).

- One meant *To fill; with derivatives referring to abundance and multitude*.
- The other meant *Flat; to spread.*

Both are implicated in the meanings of English *plain*. The link in the metaphor is the fact that this is a **Visual** metaphor. What we notice about the world is that bodies of water have flat surfaces, which expand when they are filled or overfilled.

Much the same is true of anything that can flow, and geographical plains are flat (another word that comes from the same PIE root), and look like they've been filled up, like the sea. Indeed "sea of grass" is a common metaphor for plains and steppes. PIE was formed on the steppes of Central Asia over several thousand years of wandering.

On a plain, or steppe, one can see to a distant horizon, and everything in between. It's impossible to hide, and everything is clear as far as the human eye can see. That's where the "explicit, clear" sense comes from. To see more, you just get closer, like a microscope or a telescope; it's not hidden, it's not dark, it's there and one can see it.

Really, that's all you need. 3000 years of visual experience will have a tendency to stick in the mind when the experiencers go on to other things. It's as plain (the saying goes) as the nose on your face, a piece of our optical view that we see whether we want to or not, and consequently rarely notice.

Comment: I feel very grateful for this answer, John. I can picture standing on a steppe and seeing the distant horizon. This resonates, makes sense, and integrates wonderfully within me. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer. Upvoted. In fact, the earliest sense of _plain_ is a flat terrain which is still used today. Additionally, per _OED_, _plain_ was used in geometry and other areas also for a flat surface but it is superseded by _plane_.

Comment: _Plain_ and _plane_ are the same word, just spelled differently for different contexts. Spelling is irrelevant, especially in a world of bad spellers.